# Servlet Mappings

Tags: servlets, web.xml

My problem is i mapped my servlets on web.xml. When i submit info to servlet it gives me "resuorces is not found" error. How can i solve this problem. Thanks your answers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Login" method="POST">
UserName:<input type="text" name="user_name">
<BR>
Password:<input type="password" name="password">
<BR>
<input type="submit" value="Gonder">
<BR>
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

SERVLET CODES are like this

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;


public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String usr_name;
    private String pass;
    static Logger log=Logger.getLogger(Login.class);






    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request,response);
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("C:\\Users\\AliArdaOrhan\\workspace2\\QuizProject\\WebContent\\WEB-INF\\log4j.properties");
        usr_name=request.getParameter("user_name");
        pass=request.getParameter("Password");

        try {
            if(Validation.validate(usr_name,pass)){
                RequestDispatcher rs=request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome");
                rs.forward(request, response);
            }
            else{
                RequestDispatcher rs=request.getRequestDispatcher("login");
                rs.forward(request, response);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            log.error("Cannot Validate User Information", e);
        }

    }

}
```

WEB XML CODES are like this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>QuizProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description>Login Page</description>
    <display-name>Login</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Welcome</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Welcome</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Welcome</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Welcome</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Welcome</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I posted wrong web.xml file. I change it now.

Comment: Okey i found the error. The errow is HTML sends "Password" parameter but servlet asks for "password" so validation process is not working and servlet skips if block and directly goes to else block. In else block there is a call for login but there isn't any other login servlet in my application.

Thanks for help btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change on this line

```
<form action="Login" method="POST">
```

replace "`Login`" with "`/GuestBook`"

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a servlet mapping for `Login` action in your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Login</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And make sure you restart your server after you make those changes in web.xml.

And if you are using `Servlet 3.0` then you can use annotations like below in your servlet which are equivalent to above code:

```
@WebServlet("/Login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending your form to `Login` (relative URL), but your servlet awaits at `/GuestBook`. Change the servlet mapping or form's action attribute.